# matrix inverses exam question, is my solution enough?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Im currently studying for an exam in linear algebra, and I'm unsure if my solution for this type of problem is enough, would anyone like to help me out?

Question: Let $A$= $ \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 3 \\
0 & 2 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}  $ and $C$=$ \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
1 & 2 & 3 
\end{bmatrix}  $, determine if there exists matrix $B$ so that

$\textbf{a)}$ $ABC=A$

$\textbf{b)}$ $ABC=B$

$\textbf{c)}$ $ABC=C$

My solution is following:

$\textbf{a)}$ Since $rank(A) = 2$ we know $A^{-1}$ $\exists$

$\Rightarrow AA^{-1}BC=AA^{-1}$ $\Rightarrow BC=I$

To be true $C^{-1}$ needs to exist, but since $rank(C)=1$, $C^{-1}$ $\nexists$ $\Rightarrow B$ so that $ABC=A $ $\nexists$.

$\textbf{b)}$ Since we can't "touch" $B$ since it is between $A$ and $C$ we can not create identity matrix on the right side right away. I then go on to check the dimensions of the matrices to make the matrix-multiplication work. This makes that $B$ on the left side needs to be $(3$ x $2)$ to work while $B$ on the right side will end up as $(3$ x $3)$

$\Rightarrow B$ so that $ABC=B $ $\nexists$

$\textbf{c)}$  Since $rank(A)=2$ $\Rightarrow A^{-1} $ $\exists$

$A=(2$ x $3)$ $\Rightarrow A^{-1}=$ $(3$ x $2)$ for $AA^{-1}=I$

That is, $A^{-1}$ and $B$ have same dimensions, which means $B$ so that $ABC=C$ $ \exists$

Is this solution enough, or is there any important stuff I missed out on, or misunderstood? I'm quite unsure about if my solution on $\textbf{b)}$ holds up.

Thanks!

Comment: For starters, you can't write "$A^{-1}$" for non-square matrices $A$…

Comment: I give you a hint about a):
ABC=A implies BC=I, with I being the 3-by-3 identity matrix. If you are not sure about this, prove it by contradiction, i.e. assume ABC=A with BC≠I, pre-multiplying the latter  by A gives ABC≠A, which is a contradiction. Now, rank(BC)≤min{rank(B),rank(C)}≤rank(C)=1. However rank(I)=3, therefore, the equality BC=I is not possible, for any B.